# How to create Exception and pass AggregateException as inner exception?

Tags: c#

Imagine this scenario:

```
Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // code...
    }).ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        var betterEx = new Exception("My custom message", x.Exception));
    }
    , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

However, the `betterEx.InnerException` returns `null`.

**Question**

How can I create a `new Exception` and pass `AggregateException` as the inner exception? I want to make sure all the info in the aggregate is persisted and not lost.

Comment: Don't use `ContinueWith` at all.  Just use `await`.  It's *far* easier to write code that will work properly, especially when it comes to error handling.

Comment: @servy I dont have that option unfortunately. Even if I had that option, I still would like to know how to do this.

Comment: Since you're using Task.Run you're using at least C# 5.0, and thus are able to use `await`.

Comment: @servy It is a fire-and-forget scenario but I would like to log the error in case there is an exception. I dont want to `await` it. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's not a reason to not use `await` as your means of adding continuations, it just means that something somewhere in the call stack will be starting an operation *and then not adding continuations at all*.  But when you're in a position where you *do* want to add a continuation, you should use `await` to do it.